# Переклад віршів російських письмеників українською мовою

Tags: переклад, from-russian

В школі, коли вивчали вірші російських письмеників, в підручниках часто був переклад українською мовою, але інколи дуже дивний.

Цікавить саме уривок вірша  В.Маяковського ["Послушайте!"](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5!_(%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9))

> "Ведь теперь тебе ничего?
> Не страшно?
> Да?!"
> Послушайте!
> Ведь, если звезды
> зажигают —
> значит — это кому-нибудь нужно?

Варіант перекладу українською ([Перекладач: К. Шахова](https://www.ukrlib.com.ua/world/printit.php?tid=3653)):

> "Адже тепер тобі нічого?
> Не страшно?
> Без ліхтаря?!"
> Послухайте!
> Адже, якщо зірки
> засвічують —
> виходить — без них комусь не можна?

Чому в українському перекладі з'явилось слово "ліхтар"?

Comment: Останній абзац — це два запитання, а не одне. Окрім того, «чи варто?» є завжди субʼєктивним, і на нього відповісти у рамках Stack Exchange неможливо. Окрім того, стосовно теґів: яке з цих слів — росіянізм? «Ліхтар»?

Comment: Теж згадую шкільні часи, як раз вже видали книжки зарубіжної літератури при Ющенко. Наша вчителька багато разів критикувала наявність українського перекладу та казала мов "неможливо передати сенс/суть"(подібне, розпливчато пам'ятаю(переклад)) та все ж таки — звісно варто, бо російська мова зараз "факультативна", а тобто людей які гарно володіють "язиком" після навчальних закладів буде з'являтися все менше та навіть без цього для кращого просякненням сенсу/духу.

Comment: "Чому в українському перекладі з'явилось слово "ліхтар"? " гмм, кожен перекладач передає суть через свою призму бачення.   
Тобто переклад це адаптація якоїсь інфомації під якусь іншу мову(ключеве слово адаптація). А чому саме в цьому випадку?!  ммм, можливо для усвідомленності "само брехні", мов в темряві по іншому заговориш.

Comment: Це питання не відповідає критеріям спільноти, але дам собі раду швидко поставити лише одне питання: чим російська мова так відрізняється від інших мов, що з неї не можна або не варто перекладати щось українською?

Comment: в них інша конструкція творення речень та губиться душа(останнє від шкільного вчителя про творчість Пушкіна)......... "чим російська мова так відрізняється від інших мов, що з неї не можна або не варто перекладати щось українською?" проблема не саме в російській... ммм, тобто переклад це авторська інтерпретація, а тобто наведу випадок(без джерела), відома  письменниця з південної або західної европи прочитала переклад українського та російського примірника та заявила, що загублено понад 30% сюжету. Можна казати мов перекладачі третьосортні, однак я так не скажу, бо сам стикнувся з перекладом

Comment: @bytebuster, автор відредагувала запитання (тепер воно лише про ліхтар) — як вважаєте, чи варто перевідкрити?

Comment: @ВіталійМацкевич так питання насправді політичне, а не мовознавче: чи мають люди в Україні знати російську мову, а чи мають мати переклади зі всіх мов включно з російською, а якщо вже сильно захочуть, то вчити російську на рівні зі всіма рештою мовами? Тому питання й закрите. Смисл втрачається у перекладі з будь-якої мови, але це не значить, що перекладати не варто.

Comment: @P. Vovk Я ж так і написав трохи вище та для мене воно ніяк не політичне